# EXCEL VBA use Dropdown list for changing server db connexion and choose corresponding query

Tags: sql-server, vba, drop-down-menu

I am working on an excel report with VBA and a connection to a database (on 3 different servers) sql server.
I would like to know how to use a drop-down list to change the connection with the server (I have 3).
I put my three sql queries in a tab in 3 different rows.
I created a tab with a mapping table between the drop-down list items and the database servers.

The user selects the program, and enters a number, when he clicks on the button, the connexion chain is created with the correct server and the correct request.

How to make the connection dynamic? (replace SERVER_NAME with the corresponding server)

```
'SQL REQUESTS NAMES IN THE 'SQLRequests' worksheet
Public Const QUERY_FOR_SERVER1 = "QUERY_FOR_SERVER1"
Public Const QUERY_FOR_SERVER2 = "QUERY_FOR_SERVER2"
Public Const QUERY_FOR_SERVER3 = "QUERY_FOR_SERVER3"

Public Const SERVER_NAME = "VALCOREA350,10001"
Public Const APPLICATION_NAME = "Bracket Report"

'SHEETS
'Public Const SHEET_NUMBER_SQL_REQUESTS As Integer = 5
Public Const SHEET_NAME_STARTHERE As String = "START HERE"
Public Const SHEET_NAME_SQL_REQUESTS As String = "SQLRequests"
Public Const SHEET_NAME_RESULTS As String = "Data"

'SQL OPTIONS
Public Const SQL_COMMAND_TIMEOUT As Long = 900              'sql request time out in seconds (default to 30)
Public Const DB_CATALOG As String = "DATA"                  'Schema in the DATABASE where the data has to be requested

    'Init DB connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Open connection to the DB and execute query
With cn
    .Provider = "sqloledb"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & SERVER_NAME & ";Initial Catalog=" & DB_CATALOG & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=" & APPLICATION_NAME & ";"
    .ConnectionTimeout = 30
    .CommandTimeout = SQL_COMMAND_TIMEOUT
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    'LogTRACE "Opening connection to database '" & .ConnectionString & "'", "generateReportForProgram"
    .Open
End With
```

I thank you in advance.

Slim

Comment: That looks pretty straighforward. write your different connection strings in some worksheet (preferably hidden and protected), where each is given a human readable description in column A and the actual string in column B. insert the human-readable descriptions in the drop-down list and use Index/Match to retrieve the connection string. If you have further difficulties write your attempt and we will help further.

Comment: Hello @A.S.H : Thanks for your help
I'm really in trouble
In fact, I want to create a function that gets me the value selected by the user, then make mapping with the name of the server and the request that corresponds to the chosen program.

Comment: That's no big deal, ad a column for each in the hidden WS and place them in a row in front of each choice offered to the user.